How can I retrieve a list view for CMTD that is part of a managed package?
There is a managed package called CMTD__EnhancedRelatedList__mdt. It's quite popular package used to customise related lists.
I have put together a few list views for the CMTD records that are needed to be created to be used with the package, and I would like to deploy them to other environments via git.
I see that this is not possible as, with other objects, in order to retrieve the list view metadata, one must retrieve the object. I cannot seem to retrieve the object because it is under a managed package.
Has anyone else found this issue and if so, any work arounds to this?
Regards,
Vio
